# How to add Swagger OpenAPI specification to spring boot project?

Tags: rest, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I found this project https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification
As I understood we can write documentation in `.json/.yml` files. Also, I can see in http://editor.swagger.io/ that it could be rendered to `.html` file.

My question is - how can I generate static `.html` pages from `.json/.yml` files? Is there any tutorial for spring boot application? Should I somehow set `.json/.yml` files to swagger configuration and get `.html` file with documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to generate collection of HTMLs, JavaScripts and CSS assets from the `.yml` or `.json` files. Just pass the YAML/JSON file to a server running the [Swagger UI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) and Swagger UI will dynamically generate beautiful documentation from those Swagger-compliant APIs. The [petstore](http://petstore.swagger.io/) example should give you the idea.

You can use a build engine (CI/CD server or whatever) like Jenkins to automate the documentation publishing process. For example, each REST API repository should provide at least one of these `.yml` or `.json` files (which by the way are generated by the Swagger Editor). Then after each push to that repository, Jenkins will get those `.yml` or `.json` files and upload them to your Documentation server where the Swagger UI is up and running.

REST API developers can share the API documentation link with client developers and also can be confident that each change in the `.yml` or `.json` files will be reflected in the documentation. They just need to push the changes. Since you need to maintain those Swagger-compliant APIs, I personally suggest to use the `.yml` file, simply because it's more readable.

Comment: Is it possible that swagger-ui will render json from same directory? For example I have swagger-ui in my /static content folder and also I have there swagger.json file.

Comment: @Orest It should be possible. You just pass the `yml` file link to the swagger UI

Comment: @AliDehghani - How can we pass the custom pagination details through Open API 3 UI ?